# Water Damage on PC what is broken? Motherboard is still Lighting

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu, water-damage

after a long session someone spilled a Coke/Whiskey drink onto my PC, as i *just* replaced the PCU, the wall was still open (i know.. i know) before the question came, after i realised ist *5 secs* the PC turned of by itself and i didnt try to turn it on after a day. I first lay the pc down so the motherboard is parallel to the ground, i have seen Liquid in the GPU and on the GPU, and some drips on the motherboard.

The PC was standing, so any liquid which did drip into the pc (the glass kinda blobbed it from the side if its understandable where the wall was open) the GPU catched most of it, so realy only some pinches dripped on the Motherboard, so no other component got in touch with it at all.

So, after days of drying im trying to boot... nothing, no fan spinning, no starting no nothing, the LEDs still light consistently on the Motherboard (no "trying to boot" led) just the simple LEDs always on. So that seems the PCU is still fine? its pretty new and would be sad if its broken.

i tried to boot without the GPU nothing, i simply think the GPU is dead eitherways, most liquid was in it sticky substance etc. prob broken. But the PC should start without the GPU as my mainboard also has a onboard gpu. but still nothing no fans at all (even the PCU not?).

How can i find out what is broken?

my noobish head is like

**GPU** : 100% Dead wouldnt even need to test it (was an old gtx970 eitherway its fine)

**Motherboard** : prob dead? if maybe a short circuit came from the GPU prob motherboard took it and brr itself right?

**Ram** : I have read that its resistend against short circuits and such, and that they kinda are undestroyable i kindly took them out of concideration.

**Processor** : .. Prob dead? i have no clue about it and no way to test it. But i have read as it has a heat  shield it mostly survives this.

Anyone experience with it? And could help me tell atleast what i prob have to rebuy?

Comment: What does water damage? It connects traces on electrical circuits that should not be connected, causing a short. This can damage components on a board, usually capacitors are mostly affected, but some chips could also be affected. In order to find out what is most likely struck, look where the water hit and whatever is in that area is likely dead. CPU is likely still alive, but the motherboard itself is probably dead. Good chance that replacing just the motherboard will fix your system.

Comment: Thanks ! Motherboard and GPU is already ordered, but wanted to go sure. and as the Water drops which hit the motherboard, were on the most outer rim, AND on the half of the Motherboard where no other components are that probably should be the case

Comment: Maybe the only thing damaged is your power supply. I would visually inspect all circuit boards for obviously damaged components, then clean the boards with Isopropyl Alcohol. Possibly test with a different power supply and a minimum set of cleaned/undamaged components to see what can be salvaged.